# Display values in index

Tags: javascript

I have 2 dates i.e. present date and start date. If the start date is in the past then the output will display 0 as value. However, if start date and present date are the same then, the values will be displayed according to user input.

This is what i tried so far. The dates are getting displayed but the first index is still printing 0 and not the user input when the dates are same. I am sure sure what i am doing wrong here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K65bW.png)

```
<label1>Present Value as of date</label1> <input id="presentDate" type="date">
<label2>Start date</label2> <input id="startDate" type="date">

var paymentDate = document.getElementById("presentDate").value;
var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;

if (paymentDate)
  plDate = new Date(paymentDate);

 var pdates = format(new Date(plDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd').split('-');
paymentDayValue = pdates[2];

 var presentDate, endDate,stsDate,sDay;
if (paymentDate)
  presentDate = new Date(paymentDate);
if (startDate)
  stsDate = new Date(startDate);

 var firstIndex=0;
 for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  if (dates[i]) {
      var splitDate = dates[i].split('-');
      var diffdate = splitDate[1] + "/" + presentDate.getUTCDate() + "/" + splitDate[0];
      var sdiffdate = splitDate[1] + "/" + stsDate.getUTCDate() + "/" + splitDate[0];

if (i == firstIndex)
              htmlString += "<tr><td>" + diffdate + "</td><td>" + "$" + 0 + " </td></tr>";

          else if (i == firstIndex && diffdate == sdiffdate)
              htmlString += "<tr><td>" + sdiffdate + "</td><td>" + "$" + rent + " </td></tr>";
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what `dates` contains? It seems really odd that you're smashing them apart using `split` instead of date manipulation functions.

Comment: @tadman Hi. I just updated the codes. This is just part of the code i am working on so i did not include all the codes behind the dates. Thank you.

Comment: You parse the dates, so once parsed you can compare date X with date Y using regular `<` type comparisons. I can't see why formatting and then `split` is required here.

Comment: @tadman I am using split because there's more logic to the code than what is being used here. Again, i didn't include the entire code here but just this part. I tried running this by removing 'else if' and the values worked but dates got printed twice. What is the issue here? Can you please help. Thanx.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but none of this code makes any sense. A part of that is the names of things keep changing. "Payment" date goes into "present" date, "start" date goes into "sts" date, whatever that is. `date` is an array of...dates? Which are split, recombined in a manner that's really odd, and then that data's displayed...strangely, depending on its index in the array?? This needs better variable names, functions that isolate and clearly define what they're doing, and some comments.

Comment: Unlike some languages, JavaScript format() doesn't actually change anything but the display.  In JavaScript you pull out your date parts, then put them back together as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit of a mess, I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do but I think this is the logic that you need:

```
// paymentDate is a text variable
var paymentDate = document.getElementById("presentDate").value;
// startDate is a text variable
var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;

// create new Date objects
var datePayment = new Date(paymentDate)
var dateStart = new Date(startDate)

// compare the dates
var sameDates = (datePayment.getTime() === dateStart.getTime())
var notSameDates = (datePayment.getTime() !== dateStart.getTime())
```

Comment: I think this is likely some form of what he needs, particularly the comments that break down when it's manipulating a string, when it's a date object, and when it's a date part.